# What is the namespace in utop for definitions in .ml file listed in dune's (executable ...) rule?

Tags: ocaml, utop, dune

What is the namespace of the `test0` definition in `dune utop .` environment, given the following ocaml code with dune build definition:

```bash
~/_ocaml_/n01$ cat bin/dune
(executable
 (public_name n01)
 (name main))

~/_ocaml_/n01$ cat bin/main.ml 
let test0 = "World!"
let () = print_endline  ("Hello " ^ test0)
```

When started the code produces expected result:

```bash
~/_ocaml_/n01$ dune build
~/_ocaml_/n01$ dune exec n01
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you cannot access the `test0` variable after launching `dune utop .`.

If I am not mistaken, your issue stems from the fact that the `dune top <path>` command loads libraries and not executable. Thus in your setup, the `N01` module is not part of the utop environment. The idiomatic solution is to split your source files into a library and a small executable that only contains glue code.